# ¿Cómo hacer en Django un filter() a una tabla con un ardumento QuerySet resultado de una consulta anterior?

Tags: django, filtro

Tengo las siguientes clases modelo
**Controlador**, **CodClasificacion**, **CodTipoControlador**
que están implementadas de la siguiente forma:

```
class CodClasificacion(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(db_column='Nombre', max_length=10)

class CodTipoControlador(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(db_column='Nombre', max_length=50)

class Controlador(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    id_tipocontrolador = models.ForeignKey(CodTipoControlador, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Id_TipoControlador')
    id_clasificacion = models.ForeignKey(CodClasificacion, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Id_Clasificacion')
#otros campos que no influyen en la duda
```

Esto lo obtengo de una base de datos MySQL
a la que le apliqué **inspectdb**. Los Controladores se pueden clasificar en *Sensor*, *Actuador* o *Mixto* como nombre en **CodClasificacion**.
Existen registros para **CodTipoControlador** con valores como *Temperatura*, *Relay*, *Humedad*, *PIR* etc. Deseo obtener en una vista los nombres de **CodTipoControlador** para cada *Sensor* registrado en la tabla **Controlador**.
El procedimiento que escribí identifica el id del registro con nombre "Sensor" en **CodClasificacion** y filtra los registros de **Controlador** que coinciden con el mismo. En ese punto dispongo de un QuerySet con los registros de los Controladores y por tanto de los id_tipocontrolador correspondientes a los nomencladores **CodTipoControlador**, que son mi objetivo final para la vista.
El problema es que aunque he leído la documentación no me queda claro como filtrar los registros de **CodTipoControlador** con el QuerySet de los id_tipocontrolador registrados en **Controlador**. A continuación muestro el código de la vista:

```
def sensoresinstalados(request):
    cod=CodClasificacion.objects.get(nombre='Sensor')
    sensores=Controlador.objects.filter(id_clasificacion=cod.id).values('id_tipocontrolador')
    sensores=sensores.distinct()
# aquí con mi BD obtengo los id 9 y 11 en un QuerySet
# en este punto iría algo como nombre_sensores= CodTipoControlador.objects.filter(sensores) pero como es un dict da error
```

Si me pudieran orientar para obtener el resultado final u otra vía para optimizar las consultas estaré agradecido.